# What is the meaning of entries when running 'ifconfig -a'

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, wireless-networking, google-chrome-os

When I run `ifconfig -a` on my Chromebook (both through shell inside ChromeOS and my Ubuntu chroot) I get the following entries:

```
acrbr0: ...
lo: ... 
veth_android: ...
wlan0: ...
```

I was able to find information about `wlan0` and `veth_android` but not about the others. I don't really know much about networking so I would really appreciate some run down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The entries you see ae called **[Predictable Network Interface Names](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/)**. It means that non-permanent network interfaces (ie, USB interfaces) have a name in the form of `enx<MAC_ADDR>` or `wlx<MAC_ACCR>` (or similar), so that any scripts and systems depending on that specific device will have 100% confidence that it's targeting the right device.

The Predictable Network interface naming convention goes like this :

> - Names incorporating Firmware/BIOS provided index numbers for on-board
>     devices (example: `eno1`)
> - Names incorporating Firmware/BIOS provided PCI Express hotplug slot index numbers (example: `ens1`)
> - Names incorporating physical/geographical location of the connector of the hardware (example: `enp2s0`)
> - Names incorporating the interfaces's MAC address (example: `enx78e7d1ea46da`)
> - Classic, unpredictable kernel-native ethX naming (example: `eth0`)

Coming to specific entries you asked for in question, I think [potatoman](https://superuser.com/a/1292669/814740) answered it well.

#### `lo` : Loopback interface

It's a virtual network interface that your computer uses to communicate with itself. It is used mainly for diagnostics and troubleshooting, and to connect to servers running on the local machine.

#### `wlan0` : Wireless LAN interface

wlan0 is basically your wifi card. It is wireless lan and 0 is the number of your card. The count starts from 0 and goes up (0,1,2,3,etc..). So if you had 2 wifi cards plugged in they would be represented by wlan0 and wlan1.

#### `veth_android` & `acrbr0` : Net namespaces for Android Containers

`acrbr0` is the isolated network interface that gets an IP Address from `veth_android` ( a virtual ethernet interface for Android ). They are closely related to each other. See the image below (from Page 7 in this [link](https://events.static.linuxfound.org/sites/events/files/slides/ContainersPresoLCE.pdf))to get an idea

[image: Net Namespaces in Android Network]

Feel free to add details.

Comment: and by predictable they mean not at all ;p

Answer (score 2):

`lo`: [loopback](https://askubuntu.com/questions/247625/what-is-the-loopback-device-and-how-do-i-use-it) (allows PC to connect to itself for multiple reasons [`127.0.0.1])

`acrbr0`: Not sure.

`wlan0`: Wifi/Wireless LAN

`veth_android`: [Virtual ethernet interface (Android)](https://events.static.linuxfound.org/sites/events/files/slides/ContainersPresoLCE.pdf)